# inner join on multiple tables using a single column having a 'multiplier' effect on the result values

Tags: mysql, sql

Been trying to run a simple inner join query on 4 tables (projects, tasks, spendings and donations). The joins seem to be tangling somewhere. For example SUM(tasks.budget_amount) should give a combined value of 3,211,385.21 but instead I'm getting 49,659,564.60

```
SELECT projects.id, projects.name, SUM(tasks.budget_amount) as budget, SUM(spendings.amount_spent) AS spending, SUM(donations.donation_amount) AS donation 
    FROM (((projects
    INNER JOIN tasks on tasks.project_id=projects.id)
    INNER JOIN spendings on spendings.task_id=tasks.id)
    INNER JOIN donations on donations.task_id=tasks.id)
    GROUP BY projects.id
```

Is there a way of preventing this?

Comment: This is how joins work -- they multiply the number of rows.  You should aggregate *before* doing the `join`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for the response. mind clarifying on how i should go about with the aggregation? thanks.

Comment: What version of MySQL? 5.x or 8.x? Can you use window functions?

Comment: @TheImpaler I'm using XAMPP Version 7.2.0. No, I haven't interacted with window functions before

Answer (score 1):

Remove the aggregate expressions from the SELECT list (`SUM`) and remove the `GROUP BY`, return the primary keys / unique identifiers for each table, to see what is happening.

What we will see is a semi-Cartesian product (or cross product), multiple rows from one table matching multiple rows from another table.  The SQL specification is to return all of the matches.

---

One way to avoid this is to avoid the cross product, by pre-aggregating the results, then doing the join.

As an example:

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.name
     , IFNULL(b.budget,0)    AS budget
     , IFNULL(s.spending,0)  AS spending
     , IFNULL(d.donation,0)  AS donation 
  FROM projects p
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT bt.project_id
              , SUM(bt.budget_amount) AS budget
           FROM tasks bt
         GROUP BY bt.project_id 
       ) b
    ON b.project_id = p.id
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT st.project_id
              , SUM(ss.amount_spent) AS spending
           FROM tasks st
           JOIN spendings ss
             ON ss.task_id = st.id
          GROUP BY st.project_id
       ) s
    ON s.project_id = p.id
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT dt.project_id
              , SUM(dd.donation_amount) AS donation
           FROM tasks dt
           JOIN donations dd
             ON dd.task_id = dt.id
          GROUP BY dt.project_id
       ) d
    ON d.project_id = p.id
```

Note that each of the inline views `d`, `s`, and `b` are guaranteed to return unique values of `project_id`.